# Taylor series expansion of function of a binomial random variable.

Tags: probability, taylor-expansion

I know that one can approximate the $E(X\times f(X,Y))$ by using the Taylor expansion of $X \times f(X,Y)$ when X and Y are continuous random variables. However, does the method work if $X$ and $Y$ are bernoulli random variables? I think $X\times f(X,Y)$ is not differentiable, am I right? If so, is there any way to approximate $X\times f(X,Y)$?

Comment: Whether the random variables are discrete or continuous doesn't really have any bearing on the goodness of the approximation.

Comment: So I can apply the same method for discrete variables?

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli, they can only be $0$ or $1$. Everything is discrete so you don't need to do any approximations.  When taking the expected value you can ignore the terms where $X = 0$ since you are multiplying by $0$.  So $$E(X f(X,Y)) = p_{1,0}f(1,0) + p_{1,1} f(1,1).$$ where $p_{x,y} = P(X = x, Y = y)$.